# Using regex lookbehinds in C++11

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Why can't I use lookbehinds in C++11? Lookahead works fine.

```
std::regex e("(?<=a)b");
```

This will throw the following exception:

```
The expression contained mismatched ( and ).
```

This wont throw any exception:

```
std::regex e("a(?=b)");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you are using gcc, notice that mostly all features of regex are not yet implemented.

Comment: @Carlj901 How did you setup your working environment? Which software have you downloaded and installed?

Comment: Interesting.  Documentation I have found for std::regex_search doesn't indicate that it will throw exceptions. I would have thought that this would work using the extended regex qualifier, but it doesn't.  Good question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C++11 `<regex>` uses ECMAScript's (ECMA-262) regex syntax, so it **will not** have look-behind (other flavors of regex that C++11 supports also don't have look-behind).

If your use case requires the use of look-behind, you may consider using [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/) instead.

Comment: Do you know if boost regex support it?

Comment: @Carlj901: A quick Google shows that boost supports look behind under Perl syntax.

Comment: Surprisingly, ECMAScript mode on https://regex101.com/ has lookbehind working

Comment: It's normal, lookbehind has been added to ES2018. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind

Answer (score 2):

A positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=a)` matches a location in a string that is immediately preceded with the lookbehind pattern. In case overlapping matches are not expected, like the case here, you can simply use a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and extract just the Group 1 (or even more group values if you specify more than one):

```
a(b)
```

Here is a way to extract all matches using [`std::sregex_token_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::regex rx("a(b)");             // A pattern with a capturing group
    std::string sentence("abba abec"); // A test string
    std::vector<std::string> names(std::sregex_token_iterator(
        sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), rx, 1), // "1" makes it return Group 1 values
        std::sregex_token_iterator()
    );
    for( auto & p : names ) std::cout << p << std::endl; // Print matches
    return 0;
}
```

If you only need to extract the first match use [`regex_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) (not `regex_match` as this function [requires a full string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696250/difference-between-stdregex-match-stdregex-search)):

```cpp
std::smatch sm;
if (regex_search(sentence, sm, rx)) {
    std::cout << sm[1] << std::endl;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538687/using-regex-lookbehinds-in-c11).