# Regex to extract value between a single quote and parenthesis using boost token iterator

Tags: c++, regex, tokenize

I have a value like this:

Supoose I have a string:

```
s = "server ('m1.labs.teradata.com') username ('u\'se)r_*5') password('uer 5')  dbname ('default')";
```

I need to extract

- token1 : `'m1.labs.teradata.com'`
- token2 :  `'u\'se)r_*5'`
- token3 : `'uer  5'`

I am using the following regex in cpp:

```
regex re("(\'[!-~]+\')"); 

sregex_token_iterator i(s.begin(), s.end(), re, 0);
sregex_token_iterator j;

unsigned count = 0;
while(i != j)
  {
    cout << "the token is"<<"   "<<*i++<< endl;
    count++;
  }
cout << "There were " << count << " tokens found." << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: Simpliest would be `'[^']+'`

Comment: You need to capture that part, and use `str(1)` to get the capturing group #1 value.

Comment: @Slava:


I have a value like this:

arg1('FooBar') arg2('Another Value') something else What regex will return the values enclosed in the quotation marks (e.g. FooBar and Another Value)?

I am using the following regex in cpp:

regex re("(\'[^']+\')")

Like this??

Comment: Supoose I have a string:
s = "server ('m1.labs.teradata.com') username ('u\'se)r_*5') password('uer 
 5')  dbname ('default')";

I need to extract token1 : 'm1.labs.teradata.com'
                           token2 :  'u\'se)r_*5'
                           token3 : 'uer  5'

Comment: Do you have to use the `sregex_token_iterator`rather than the regular one?

Comment: You should put examples in your question that are relevant to your problem. Perhaps edit your question to include your new examples? They turn it into a different question.

Comment: No I can use anything else , but it should extract the string.

Comment: [Here is your solution](https://ideone.com/IqtxgJ). Here is a [safer variation](https://ideone.com/78WL8W).

Comment: This utterly trivial search doesn't need the complexity of regular expressions. Use `start = std::string::find('\'')` to find the beginning of the target text and then use `end = std::string::find('\'', start)` to find the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to extract string in the form 'm1.labs.teradata.com' 'u\'se)r_*5' 'uer 5' 
With the single quotes around it, is their a way?

And also my string can contain special character such as "user')5" . With your regex I am not able to do so.
I have used the regex as asked in the question but that does not work for me.  Please can you help me out with this?

And also can you please explain the regex you have written

Comment: [With single quotes](https://ideone.com/g6WA5u) and [with both types of quotes](https://ideone.com/x65hOo).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   The one with single qoutes one:

If I have a string username
 ('u\\'se)'r_*5'), I want to include the quote which is before r,  but the regex is  not doing that. Thanks for your time. I really need the help.

Comment: No idea what the rules are now. I cannot help when example strings are inconsistent.  Ask Slava, he seems to understand your issue better.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   Can you help me out with how can I involve a single quotes withing the string which I am extracting?

Example :  user'5

Comment: Do you mean `username ('u\\'se)r_*5')` please correct you question or even better provide [mcve]

Comment: @Slava -:
Suppose my string is:

"server ('m1.labs.teradata.com') username ('u\'se)r_*5') password('uer  5') dbname ('default')";

Consider the username ('u\'se)r_*5') 

As you can see I am trying to escape  the single quote in " 'u\'se)r_5' " using     "  \'  ", so the output token looks like 'u'se)r_5'.  Can You please help me out with the regex for the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not expect symbol `'` inside your string then `'[^']+'` would match what you need:

```
regex re("'[^']+'");
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/cKwDR1)
Result:

```
the token is   'FooBar'
the token is   'Another Value'
There were 2 tokens found.
```

if you do not need single quotes to be part of match change code to:

```
regex re("'([^']+)'");

sregex_token_iterator i(s.begin(), s.end(), re, {1});
```

[another live example](http://ideone.com/EBkRGn)

```
the token is   FooBar
the token is   Another Value
There were 2 tokens found.
```

Comment: [OP already mentioned the string may contain escaped single quotes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192314/regex-to-extract-value-between-a-single-quote-and-parenthesis-using-boost-token/45192548?noredirect=1#comment77352207_45192314)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew where?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Comments are not part of the question, OP needs to fix the question. Currently this answer is correct.

Comment: I do not understand what OP needs now.

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex for this string would be

```
(?:'(.+?)(?<!\\)')
```

https://regex101.com/r/IpzB80/1

Comment: The output string should contain escaped single quote, but the regex givven by you does not work.

Comment: Try this string :

It is not working:
server ('m1.labs.teradata.com') username ('u\'se)r_*5') password('ue/'r5') dbname ('default')

Comment: @Pradeep C++11 regex does not support look behind - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538687/using-regex-lookbehinds-in-c11